# Should I cut off the brown/white branches of my asparagus fern?

Tags: pruning, ferns, asparagus, browning

My fern sits in the office and has many of these light brown or white branches. Should I remove these by cutting them off, and how can I prevent them from happening again?

Thanks for the help!

[image: My asparagus fern.]

Comment: Dead branches cannot repair themselves, so they can go. Check if you're watering too much or too little. Repot if 5 years have passed!